# Method that walks through combinations and counting those who passes condition

Tags: java, combinations, counting

I should find every 5-number combination of the values 0 1 2 3 4 5 where 0 is not first and one digit is not repeated more than 1 time.The method shall return the number of valid combinations.

Valid combinations:

```
1 0 0 2 1
1 2 3 4 5
1 1 2 2 3
```

invalid combinations:

```
0 1 2 3 4 (0 cant be first)
2 3 3 3 5 (not allowed with 3 of the same digits)
0 1 2 3 4 5 (6 digit numbers not allowed)
```

I did a similar task with permutations, but I'm not quite sure how to approach this one. The right answer is 5100 (I solved it mathematically).

Comment: where's the problem? you've already calculated it on a piece of paper, just translate the calculation into code

Comment: I feel like it's more a Mathematical related problem. Anyway, should you find the valid pattern within an input or just output the number of different combination possible ?

Comment: Thanks for fast replies.
Solving this mathematically is quite easy, but in my task i was specified to run through all the possible combinations and only count those passing the condition, and return that number. Thats something i didnt do on paper. 

I cant wrap my head around the algorythm that walks through all the combinations, and there is where my problem lies(i think)

Comment: I think you're thinking too much. You have 5 digits, with 6 different ciffers. With one for-loop you can go from 0 to 100000 you'll browse more than all possibilities, then check if each number is valid or not.
If you want only to check numbers that contains your digits, then you can go with 5 nested for-loop that go from 0 to 5. Each loop representing a digit.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to write the isValid function and try the following pseudo-code

```
NB_SOLUTION = 0
FOR i = 0 ; i < 100000; i++
    If isValid(i)
        NB_SOLUTION ++
```

EDIT : This is what I did, and I find the same value as you found.

```
public static void computeExample() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        if(isValid(i)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
}

public static int[] splitCiffers(int number) {
    int tmp = number;
    int unite = tmp % 10;
    tmp = (tmp - unite) / 10;
    int dizaine = tmp % 10;
    tmp = (tmp - dizaine) / 10;
    int centaine = tmp % 10;
    tmp = (tmp - centaine) / 10;
    int millier = tmp % 10;
    tmp = (tmp - millier) / 10;
    int dix_millier = tmp % 10;

    int[] retour = new int [5];
    retour[0] = dix_millier;
    retour[1] = millier;
    retour[2] = centaine;
    retour[3] = dizaine;
    retour[4] = unite;

    return retour;
}

public static boolean isValid(int number) {
    boolean isValid = true;
    int[] digitByDigit = splitCiffers(number);
    int[] digitAllowed = new int[6];
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        digitAllowed[i] = 0;
    }

    if(digitByDigit[0] == 0) {
        isValid = false;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if(digitByDigit[i] < 0 || digitByDigit[i] > 5) {
            isValid = false;
        } else {
            digitAllowed[digitByDigit[i]]++;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        if(digitAllowed[i] > 2) {
            isValid = false;
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: I understand this, that i must loop through the solutions and only cound those valid. But where do i start? Is there any method that gives me the next combination?

Comment: First you have to declare and define the isValid method :
    public boolean isValid(int number);

Comment: Check the edited version, with the detailed solution. The harder part was to split the number in different ciffers !